# Unable to execute Http request: Read timed out while invoking AWS Lambda Function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am using software.amazon.awssdk version 2.18.21 to invoke Lambda function from spring boot application.
While invoking Lmabda function which takes approx 2-3 minutes to finish always throws Timed out exception.
Is there any timeout related configuration need to be set in my code to resolve this?

```
//imports from 
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeResponse;

//Calling Lambda Function
try{
  LambdaClient client = LambdaClient.builder().build();
  InvokeRequest req = InvokeRequest.builder().functionName("abc").build();
  InvokeResponse res = client.invoke(req); //Exception here
  String respnonse = res.payload().asUtf8String();
  System.out.println(response);
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute Http request: Read timed out 
---
Caused by:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read Timed Out
```

Comment: take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration-apache.html

Comment: i added Apache client and now able to get response. Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration-apache.html), you can configure the timeouts on Apache HTTP client. While building the `LambdaClient`, just specify this custom HTTP client

```
LambdaClient client = LambdaClient.builder().httpClientBuilder(ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                      .maxConnections(100)
                      .socketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                      .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                    )
                    .build();
 InvokeRequest req = InvokeRequest.builder().functionName("abc").build();
 InvokeResponse res = client.invoke(req);
```

Additional gradle dependency required:

`implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client:2.18.25")`

Comment: I need to convert this Lambda invocation to asynchronous. I posted here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647317/how-to-invoke-software-amazon-awssdk-asynchronous-lambda-function-from-java> . Can you help me on this approach please.