# How to Invoke software.amazon.awssdk Asynchronous Lambda function from Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am using software.amazon.awssdk version 2.18.21 to invoke Lambda function from spring boot application. While invoking Lambda function which takes approx 2-3 minutes to finish  throws Http status 504: Gateway Time-out Exception.
I have been suggested to use Asynchronous Call to invoke Lambda function and then read the response. How can i convert this existing code to asynchronous call and get response to verify if it was success or error?

```
//imports from 
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.ApacheHttpClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeResponse;

//Calling Lambda Function
try{
  LambdaClient client = LambdaClient.builder().httpClientBuilder(ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                      .maxConnections(100)
                      .socketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                      .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                    ).build();
  InvokeRequest req = InvokeRequest.builder().functionName("abc").build();
  InvokeResponse res = client.invoke(req);
  String respnonse = res.payload().asUtf8String();
  System.out.println(response);
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edited: Tried below but unable to implement CompletableFuture. Can you suggest how to implement it for Lambda function and get response

```
try{
SdkAsyncHttpClient client = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder().readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).build();

  LambdaAsyncClient lambdaClient = LambdaAsyncClient .builder().httpClient(client).build();
  InvokeRequest req = InvokeRequest.builder().functionName("abc").invocationType("EVENT").build();
CompletableFuture<InvokeResponse> request = lambdaClient.invoke(req);
  //InvokeResponse res = client.invoke(req);
  //String respnonse = res.payload().asUtf8String();
  //System.out.println(response);
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform Lambda operations using Asynchronous calls with the Java V2 API, use this:

[LambdaAsyncClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/lambda/LambdaAsyncClient.html)

The call the **invoke** method:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/lambda/LambdaAsyncClient.html#invoke(software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest)

The patten to use Async methods are similar no matter what the service use. For example, most calls involve using  **CompletableFuture**. Then you code the logic you want within the **whenComplete** code block.

To learn about the patterns, read this part of the Java V2 DEV Guide:

[Asynchronous programming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html)

For example, this code example is from that topic.

```
public class DynamoDBAsyncListTables {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // Create the DynamoDbAsyncClient object
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbAsyncClient client = DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        listTables(client);
    }

    public static void listTables(DynamoDbAsyncClient client) {

        CompletableFuture<ListTablesResponse> response = client.listTables(ListTablesRequest.builder()
                .build());

        // Map the response to another CompletableFuture containing just the table names
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> tableNames = response.thenApply(ListTablesResponse::tableNames);

        // When future is complete (either successfully or in error) handle the response
        tableNames.whenComplete((tables, err) -> {
            try {
                if (tables != null) {
                    tables.forEach(System.out::println);
                } else {
                    // Handle error
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            } finally {
                // Lets the application shut down. Only close the client when you are completely done with it.
                client.close();
            }
        });
        tableNames.join();
    }
}
```